# Custom Events for Integers

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, integer

I know how silly this may sound, but is there a way to attach an event to an integer?

For example, if you're in a while loop and you do: i++; is it at all possible to do something like this?:

```
int i;

Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   i.MaximumNumberReached += new IntegerMaximumNumberReachedEventArgs();
}

while(x != y)
{
   i++
}

private void MaximumNumberReached(object sender, EventAgrs e)
{
   if(e.Value == 7)
   {
      this.Dispose(true);
   }
}
```

Or should I just stop using my imagination so much?

Thank you

Comment: Any class or struct with value semantics should be immutable in .net(and `int` is immutable). And an event on an immutable value like object doesn't make much sense IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, no, you can't do that. You could if, say, you had your own class representing numbers and overloaded relevant operators such that they initiated certain events, but you can't invent events and attach them to existing classes (aside, say, from using an AOP framework and hooking into certain methods).

Secondly, no, don't stop using your imagination. You may be interested in the following article: [Arithmetic Overflow Checking](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/overflow_checking.aspx).

Comment: That's a shame. Hmm, that article looks interesting, I'll check it out now. And thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't add events to a type outside of your control, and events on structs is usually a very bad idea; but: the best approach here would be to use a *property*:

```
private int someMeaningfulName;
public int SomeMeaningfulName {
    get { return someMeaningfulName; }
    set {
        // pre-validation checks and "changing" notification
        someMeaningfulName = value;
        // side effect code and "changed" notification
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension methods? Not events but you can do something similar. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a = 10;
        a.MaximumNumberReached();
    }
}

public static class Extns
{
    public static void MaximumNumberReached(this int number)
    {
        if (number == 7)
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```